# Как заменять объекты на несколько элементов из массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Вот код:

```py
txt = '5+5 == &{5+5}, 6+6 == &{6+6}'
nums = [10, 12];
for i in nums:
   txt = txt.replace(...
```

Я хочу заменить `&{5+5}` на элемент из массива `nums` но как? Пожалуйста решите!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Через replace это не получится сделать. Используйте re.sub

Answer (score 2):

с помощью `re.sub` получится красивее, а если через `replace`, то у меня получилось такое безобразие:

```
txt = '5+5 == &{5+5}, 6+6 == &{6+6}'
nums = [10, 12]

txt = ','.join(i.replace(i[i.index('&'):], str(j)) for i,j in zip(txt.split(','), nums))

print(txt)  # 5+5 == 10, 6+6 == 12
```

**UPD** с регуляркой вот так получилось:

```
from re import sub

nums = iter(nums)
txt = sub(r'&\{.+?\}', lambda m: str(next(nums)), txt)
```